# Substring error converting Int to String

Tags: java

```
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    lotteryNumber = (int)(Math.random()*10);
    System.out.print(lotteryNumber);

    lotteryNumberFinal = Integer.toString(lotteryNumber);
} 

System.out.println(lotteryNumberFinal);
```

I'm trying to figure out how to turn the 3 random numbers into strings and then be able to substring out each one to a different variable, but my **lotteryNumberFinal** string is always only being set to the last random number rather then all three.

Here's a pic of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: you could use += instead =

Comment: Yes, either concatenate the Strings together or make an array of Strings if you want to keep them individually for later use

Comment: What does "substring out each one to a different variable" mean?

Comment: firstNumber = lotteryNumberFinal.substring(0,1);

secondNumber = lotteryNumberFinal.substring(1,2);

thirdNumber = lotteryNumberFinal.substring(2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do it:

```
lotteryNumberFinal = "";
for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        lotteryNumber = (int)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.print(lotteryNumber);

        lotteryNumberFinal += lotteryNumber;
    } 

System.out.println(lotteryNumberFinal);
```

Notice that now you don't need to do the Integer.toString conversion, since the int will be coerced to String representation when you cat it onto another String.

You can then use substring to get the individual numbers if you want... but an array would be the right way to do it.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much - Can't do arrays since this is a project for my class and we haven't reached arrays yet :p

Comment: Time limit on it @getlost

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning lotteryNumber within the for loop that's why it is override the value and keep the last value. In you case you want all the lotteryNumber in a lotteryNumberFinal variable you can use the below code in this case you don't require explicit Integer to String conversion also-

```
    String lotteryNumberFinal = "";  //define String variable where you want to concatenate your lotterNumber. 

    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        lotteryNumber = (int)(Math.random()*10);

        System.out.print(lotteryNumber);

        lotteryNumberFinal += lotteryNumber; // in this case you don't need to do Integer to String conversion because it will concatenate your value in a String value so it will automatically converted into string.
}
```